# I am not able to open my google appmaker project

Tags: google-app-maker

My App Maker project was working perfectly earlier. Suddenly, I am not able to open one of my projects, and progress spinner keeps on running.  After some time It is giving Unexpected client error.

I can open other projects and create new project, but this one is not opening the project what I want.

Screenshots:

The error toast:

[image]

Progress spinner:

[image: screenshot2 progress spinner]

Browswer log:

[image: screenshot3 browser log]

Comment: This happend to me once when I change the name of a page I was working with on the app start up script. Have you modified something recently?

Comment: No Morfinismo, I have not modified any page. It suddenly stops working. Any workaround/solution for this problem, I raised the ticket but didn't get any reply from Google :(

Comment: Without looking your app. It is really difficult to say what's wrong. If you raised a ticket with G Suite Support, ask for the API Team. They might be able to help.

Comment: Thanks, Morfinismo for your response.

Comment: Yes, I have raised the ticket. They took  little bit  of time to fix and now it is working.